# Use different node module depending on environment?

Tags: node.js, npm, config, local

I have a npm package that we use for multiple projects. Currently when I want to make a change to something on these projects that requires a change on the npm package I need to make a change to the npm package, submit a pr, wait for someone to merge it for me and then I can actually test the changes I made on the other projects (no testing is set up currently sadly).

What I want to do is on the other projects have a way to install / use the local module instead of the global one so I can test the full flow before I submit any prs. Im using config package and ideally I can set it up so if I use a specific config file it defaults to local npm package instead of global.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are describing, take look at the `link` command offered by package managers to help solve this:

- https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link#search
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link